# Change location of image when another one is touched CSS

Tags: css

I want to switch person1's image to person2's image when you hover over the background with your mouse. Ive tried to just switch the "right-bottom" code from the 2 images but I don't know how to do it and ive been searching google for the past hour now.

How do I change another element when one is touched?

This is my current code

```css
.background
    {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .person1
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        right: 251px;
        bottom: 169px;
    }
    
    .person2
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        right: 749px;
        bottom: 221px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Document</title>
            <link href="assets-css/heads.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <img src="assets-css/images/background.png" alt="background" class="background">
            <img src="assets-css/images/person1.png" alt="personright" class="person1">
            <img src="assets-css/images/person2.png" alt="personleft" class="person2">        
    
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Showing us only CSS without any HTML it is supposed to apply to, is pretty pointless. Please get into the habit of always providing a proper [mre] with questions like this.

Comment: Ive added the HTML it is supossed to apply to.

Comment: You can use the _general sibling combinator_ to select following siblings of the first image, and you can combine it with the `:hover` pseudo class. `.background:hover ~ .person1 { /* styles to format .person1 when .background is hovered go here */ }`

Comment: -CBroe, Thank you this was what I was looking for!